# Sanity check: is Q necessary for (P and Q)?

Tags: logic

I believe the following is trivial, but please sanity-check my reasoning. Is the following correct? (If not - please elaborate.)

**Claim**

$Q$ is necessary for $P \wedge Q$.

**Background**

Swartz defines a necessary condition as a condition whose falsity guarantees falsity. Formally, he says that if condition Q is necessary for condition P, then P must be false if Q is false (the falsity of Q guarantees the falsity of P). (Swartz, 1997) Based on this definition, I postulate that $Q$ is necessary for $P \wedge Q$ because $Q$ being false always guarantees that $P \wedge Q$ is false.

**Proof**

Hammack observes that the grammatical construction "A is a necessary condition for B" means $B \implies A$. (p.44, Hammack, 2018) As such, we expect $Q$ to be necessary for $P \wedge Q$ if the relation $B \implies A$ is true for $B = P \wedge Q$ and $A = Q$, such that $(P \wedge Q) \implies Q$ is true.

Based on the truth table of conditional statements

| $P$ | $Q$ | $P \implies Q$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T | T | T |
| T | F | F |
| F | T | T |
| F | F | T |

we get that

| $Q \wedge P$ | $Q$ | $P$ | $Q \wedge P \implies Q$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F | F | F | T |
| F | F | T | T |
| F | T | F | T |
| T | T | T | T |

As such, the relation $Q \wedge P \implies Q$ is always true. Based on Hammack's definition, we conclude that $Q$ is a necessary condition for $Q \wedge P$.

QED.

**Bibliography**

Swartz, Norman. “The Concept of Necessary Conditions and Sufficient Conditions,” 1997. [https://www.sfu.ca/~swartz/conditions1.htm](https://www.sfu.ca/%7Eswartz/conditions1.htm) (accessed August 24, 2021)

Hammack, Richard H. Book of Proof. Third Edition (3.2), 2018.

Comment: "and" is saying each of P and Q is necessary (and together are sufficient)

Comment: Thanks for verifying.

Comment: Swarts says q is necessary for p when $\lnot q \implies \lnot p.$ Since an implication is equivalent to its contrapositive, that is the same as $p \implies q.$

Comment: @coffeemath Aha! That clarifies a lot! =)